# How to enable ‘Forms for Excel’ in SharePoint/Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I am an Office 365 global administrator, looking after two SharePoint sites. One has menu items for Forms, but the other does not.

The site that works is new, created since we started using Forms. The other site is older.

On the old site, the Edit New menu dialogue does not work as expected. I can remove and re-add existing items, but nothing happens when I select Forms for Excel (or Excel survey or Visio drawing) and click Save.

[image: screen-shot of Edit New menu].

Another difference between the two sites is that, for the old site, the Forms menu item is missing in Excel.

I need to enable Forms in the old site. Cannot anyone suggest what is wrong?

Comment: Is the "old" site a modern site?

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan - if you mean 'old' = 'classic' then no, it's a new type. I did try switching to 'classic SharePoint', but that did not help.However, Office Graph is off, for both sites.

Comment: I get the exact same problem, does anyone get a fix for this? Thanks

Comment: @user92760 As per my answer below https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/282782/62819, I had to create a new site. Migrating data is now easy - click the 3 vertical dots next to a folder or file name and select Move or Copy.

Answer (score 0):

Go to document library settings> Create View> Standard View> Name view "All Items">Check the option to be " Make this the default view ">OK.

Go back to the document Library> New> The default option will show as expected.

And then remove previous not working properly view to compare the result.

If the issue still exists, I suggest you rise a ticket to MS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it did not work. Can you explain why changing view options should help?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Julie_MSFT, the problem was reported to Microsoft, who are unable to help.

I have also spotted other problems with this faulty site. There are no links to Teams and no automatically-created Group.

It looks like I will have to build another site and migrate all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and connecting a Microsoft 365 group with the Sharepoint site (which was using the "Team site (classic experience)" template) seems to have solved the problem.

Hope this helps other people!

Comment: It seems that Microsoft's thinking has evolved. At one time, SharePoint was a stand-alone product, now it is bottom of an hierarchy, with Groups at the top and Teams in the middle. Starting with a group is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the template the site was created from. I can't see FORMS FOR EXCEL in my communications sites but I can in my team sites. I don't want to mess with the features but I know you can turn on missing features in a communication site to make it run like a teams site (but this has consequences).